# How should I solve error “there is no package called ‘rspatial’?

Tags: r

I'm trying to install `rspatial` package using:

```
if (!require("rspatial")) devtools::install_github('rspatial/rspatial')
```

but I received below error:

> Error: Failed to install 'rspatial' from GitHub:
>     (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/A02243~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpgx3SZq/file16441e95c6/rspatial_1.0-0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
>
> there is no package called ‘rspatial’

Also, I used:

```
install.packages("rspatial")
```

and I received below warning
Warning in install.packages :

> package ‘rspatial’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)

Is there any other ways that will install `rspatial` on R version 3.5.2?

Thanks.

Comment: you sure it's not `r-spatial` instead of `rspatial`???

Comment: Actually, I was able to install from githab running your command: `devtools::install_github('rspatial/rspatial')`

Comment: Looking at the repo, I'm a little confused. Like @VitaliAvagyan, I figured you meant "r-spatial", as in the folks who develop packages such as sf. This is some other package that, based on the source, seems to only download data from a UC Davis website. The warning from `install.packages` is because the package isn't on CRAN. Is this definitely the package you're trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

3.5.2 has some issues with devtools - try updating processx package and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: `devtools` does not import or even suggest `processx`, how would updating the latter affect things? This seems more like a comment than an answer; if this is indeed the case, perhaps you can expand on why you think it's related?